# Deployment script - Not sure where to start

Tags: deployment, batch-file, setup-deployment, web-deployment, putty

Trying to write a script to automatically deploy an application from my windows machine to a remote linux server.

I've been struggling for a while trying to figure out an acceptable method to do this.

The script needs to:

- Copy some files from my machine to the server (python code files, javascripts, html files, etc...)
- SSH into the remote linux server and restart the dev server application

I'm not sure if I should be using a windows batch file for this, a script that is run by putty, or something else that I am not a aware of.

A poke in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)? You'd set up pubkey authentication and just scp the file.

Answer (score 1):

[Kwatee](http://Www.kwatee.net) (I'm the author) is a lightweight deployment tool that solves exactly this problem. It is easy to configure with a simple web interface and can be used to trigger deployments via a mouse click or via command line scripts which you can include in a build process.